# Deleting specified row in google sheets with app script code . (Android)

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to delete a row containing a specified id in google sheet using android studio. I used below code for adding items to the table. Now i need the app script code for deleting the row specified. Anyone please help!

```
function addItem(e){

var date =  new Date();

var id  =  sheet.getLastRow(); 

var itemName = e.parameter.itemName;

var brand = e.parameter.brand;

sheet.appendRow([date,id,itemName,brand]);

   return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);



}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TextFinder Class to find any string within a Range, a Sheet or a Spreadsheet.

I've made a sample code that does what you are looking to, it make a search for a string on a certain column, if found, it deletes the that row:

```js
function searchString(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(YOURSPREADSHEET).getSheets()[0];
  var column = 3
  var search_string = "myId"

  var range = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow());
  var textFinder = range.createTextFinder(search_string)
  try {
    search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRowIndex()
    Logger.log("Deleting row: " + search_row)
    sheet.deleteRow(search_row);
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log("Search string: '" + search_string + "' does not exist on column " +column);
  }
}
```

**Google documentation about:**

How to create a text finder for a Range:

[CreateTextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Methods allowed for the TextFinder Class:

[Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Let me know if it does not work, also, please, check the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers